# Nested Ajax call cannot see its functions parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I am running an ajax call to retrieve a token, then once done I am running another ajax call to hit a specific endpoint. This is all wrapped inside of a function called `addAdmin` as such:

```
addAdmin: function(admin_data){

    console.log(admin_data) //returns an object

    // Get the access tolken
    var getAccessToken = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://somesite.com',
        data: d,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function(response){
            console.log("Token success.")
        },
        error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("request for token failed: ",jqXHR , textStatus, errorThrown);
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    });

    // when the ajax call is done (the token is received)
    getAccessToken.done(function(data) {

        console.log(admin_data) // returns undefined

        // hit the add endpoint url
        var downloadurl = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://somesite.com/add",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: admin_data,
            success: function(response){
                ...
            },
            error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("request for download url failed: ", textStatus, errorThrown, jqXHR);
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        })


     })

  },
```

The problem is, that I need the `admin_data` to be visible in the second ajax call, but I can't figure out how to retrieve it since its out of scope. What is the recommended way of doing this?

Comment: Have you tried it? `admin_data` is definitely accessible as you have it written.

Comment: @MikeC Yes I have tried it. `admin_data` is undefined where the console.log() is. I have also added a console.log() to the first ajax call and it logs the proper data. See revisions.

Comment: Then you must be re-assigning it somewhere and not showing us. [Your code works just fine.](https://jsfiddle.net/w5w293vz/)

Comment: @MikeC You are right. You can post an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 0):

Use the response from your ajax success function and pass it into your own function as a parameter/argument:

```
success: function(response) {
    this.getAccessToken(response);
}

getAccessToken = function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    $.ajax({
        ...
        data: response,
        ...
    });
}
```